# TinyMCE 6 resulting in a data:image object over uploading via script provided

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Our TinyMCE self hosted script:

```
const example_image_upload_handler = (blobInfo, progress) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.withCredentials = false;
  xhr.open('POST', '/p/account/project-post-image-upload');

  xhr.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
    progress(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
  };

  xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.status === 403) {
      reject({ message: 'HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status, remove: true });
      return;
    }

    if (xhr.status < 200 || xhr.status >= 300) {
      reject('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
      return;
    }

    const json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
      reject('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
      return;
    }

    resolve(json.location);
  };

  xhr.onerror = () => {
    reject('Image upload failed due to a XHR Transport error. Code: ' + xhr.status);
  };

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('tinymce_file_upload', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

  xhr.send(formData);
});
  
tinymce.init({
  selector: '.tinymce',
  model: 'dom',
  plugins: 'autoresize image link lists',
  autoresize_bottom_margin: 20,
  skin: 'theme',
  content_css: 'tinymce/skins/content/theme/content.min.css',
  min_height: 300,
  toolbar_sticky: true,
  contextmenu: 'link image paste',
  toolbar: ' undo redo|formatselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | image link bullist numlist | hr',
  block_formats: 'Paragraph=p; Header 1=h1; Header 2=h2; Header 3=h3; Header 4=h4; Header 5=h5; Header 6=h6',
  menubar: false,
  media_dimensions: false,
  object_resizing : false,
  image_uploadtab: true,
  images_upload_handler: example_image_upload_handler,
  images_file_types: 'jpeg,jpg,png,gif',
  automatic_uploads: false,
  image_dimensions: false,
  image_class_list: [
    {title: 'Regular', value: 'tinymce_full_width img-fluid'}
  ],
  relative_urls : false,
  document_base_url: "/",
  setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on('init', function () {
      editor.getContainer().style.transition='border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out';
    }).on('focus', function(e) {
        editor.getContainer().style.boxShadow='0 0 0 .2rem rgb(54 97 11 / 25%)';
    }).on('blur', function(e){
        editor.getContainer().style.boxShadow='';
    }).on('keyup', function(e){

    });
  }
});
```

We have a function that uploads an image to our server, however as of recently, it ignores that script and just uploads a data:image within the src. How do we mitigate this from happening? Am I missing something that's ignoring the upload script?

Comment: Have you made any changes to your front end code? If not, it might be worth checking whether another browser or older version of the browser you're using exhibits the same issue. Next place to look for clues would be in the Sources panel in dev tools and add a breakpoint in TinyMCE code before when `images_upload_handler` is called and step through to determine what causes your function not to run.

Comment: The odd thing is all other code is working (tinyMCE is loading, I tried removing options and it is reflected), for some reason, tinyMCE is just ignoring the function I put in? Unless its because some option is overriding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though I figured out the issue.

In TinyMCE 6, if you are providing a script via `images_upload_handler`, then `automatic_uploads` must be set to `true` or else it will ignore the script and automatically use data as the source to "upload" an image. Take a look at TinyMCE's docs [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/latest/file-image-upload/#automatic_uploads), even though it doesn't explicitly state this, this is what got my script to work.